# How to select latest objects using max(date) with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

As I mentioned in my answer, this is the wrong approach.

My statement:

```py
db.session.query(
  m.SiteServicePrice, func.max(m.SiteServicePrice.created).label('latest')).filter(
    m.SiteServicePrice.site_id == 2001).group_by(m.SiteServicePrice.service_id).all()
```

I'd like to get back a list of m.SiteServicePrice objects, not a list of tuples.

This:

```py
[<SiteServicePrice(site_id:2001 service_id:12 created:2019-01-30 03:25:31)>,
 <SiteServicePrice(site_id:2001 service_id:21 created:2019-01-30 03:25:31)>,
 <SiteServicePrice(site_id:2001 service_id:37 created:2019-01-30 03:25:31)>]
```

instead of this:

```py
[(<SiteServicePrice(site_id:2001 service_id:12 created:2019-01-30 03:25:31)>, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 22, 31, 35)),
 (<SiteServicePrice(site_id:2001 service_id:21 created:2019-01-30 03:25:31)>, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 22, 31, 54)),
 (<SiteServicePrice(site_id:2001 service_id:37 created:2019-01-30 03:25:31)>, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 28, 22, 32, 15)))]
```

Is there a way to keep `func.max(m.SiteServicePrice.created)` as part of the query, and instruct SQLAlchemy not to include it in the result?

I know i can extract m.SiteServicePrice objects from the result using list comprehension or by other means, but I'm curious if there's a way to do this with SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my original SQL query and SQLAlchemy statement were incorrect.

Original sql query:

```sql
select 
  max(created), 
  created, 
  service_id, c_price, s_price 
from 
  site_service_prices 
where 
  site_id = 2001 
group by service_id;
```

Here i'm not including all keys from `select` in `group by`. MySQL and MariaDB don't treat this as an error, which it is. [Explanation from MariaDB knowledge-base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/maxdate-group-by-behaviour/#comment_2876)

To get a list of `latest` items from a query using max(date_field) a subquery is required.

this is the correct query:

```sql
   1 SELECT
   2   id, site_id, service_id, created
   3 FROM
   4   site_service_prices join(
   5     SELECT
   6       site_id, service_id, max(created) AS created
   7     FROM
   8       site_service_prices
   9     WHERE
  10       site_id = 1
  11     GROUP BY
  12       site_id, service_id
  13   ) t2
  14 USING (
  15   site_id, service_id, created
  16 );
```

and this is what SQLAlchemy query should look like:

```py
 # create a subquery with IDs and max date
 sq = db.session.query(
         m.SiteServicePrice.service_id.label('service_id'),
         func.max(m.SiteServicePrice.created).label('created')).filter(
               m.SiteServicePrice.site_id == 1).group_by(
                   m.SiteServicePrice.service_id).subquery()
 # join with subquery
 db.session.query(m.SiteServicePrice).join(sq,
     and_(m.SiteServicePrice.service_id == sq.c.service_id,
          m.SiteServicePrice.created == sq.c.created)).filter(
              m.SiteServicePrice.site_id == 1).order_by(
                  m.SiteServicePrice.created.desc()).all()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just iterate over them with simple for loop and save in different array.

Comment: I know i can do that. I even mentioned it at the end of my question. I'd like to know if there's a sqlalchemy way to do what i want.